# woof does not work with files whose names contains spaces or brackets

Tags: bash, scripts, nautilus

I wrote a bash script and put it in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`.

In nautilus, if I right click on the file and select the script menu, it will start http server to share the current file, and a QR code will display, so mobile can scan the url to download the file. The server will stop when you close the QR pic window.

It all works, but when filenames contains space or brackets, I cannot download the file.

```
▶ cat ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/share-http.bash 
#!/bin/bash

port=8080
pkill woof
file=`echo -n $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS|sed 's/\ *$//'|sed 's/\ /\\\ /g'`
echo $file >> ~/tmp
woof -c 4 -p $port \'$file\' &
# woof -c 4 -p $port $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS &
url=`ifconfig|awk '/inet /&&!/127./{print $2}'|sed 's/.*://'`
qrencode -s 5 -o /tmp/url.png "http://$url:$port"
eog /tmp/url.png && pkill woof
```

This script needs woof+qrencode to run.

I find the string `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` has a suffix space, so I modify the code.

In bash, this should work:

```
▶ woof -c 4 -p 8080 '/home/eexp/Download/IMG_20161024_132 037.jpg'
```

but it still fails. You see the commands in ps has apostrophe even if it has backslash before space.

```
▶ pgrep woof
13109 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/woof -c 4 -p 8080 '/home/eexp/Download/IMG_20161024_132 037.jpg'
▶ pgrep woof
13531 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/woof -c 4 -p 8080 '/home/eexp/Download/IMG_20161024_132\ 037.jpg'
```

Comment: Quote your variables. http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/70524

Answer (score 1):

In GNU/Linux anything except `/` and `\0` (ASCII NUL) are allowed as a valid filename constituent character. So space, tab, even newline are valid filename constituent characters. When you have any such filename, you need to use any trivial escaping mechanism to get literal meaning of the character(s).

For example, for a filename like:

```
foo bar spam.txt
```

you can use single quotes, double quotes or `\` for escaping the spaces:

```
'foo bar spam.txt'
"foo bar spam.txt"
foo\ bar\ spam.txt
```

single quotes are recommended as with a filename like `foo $bar spam.txt` if you use double quotes the shell will take `$bar` as a variable expansion, same goes for unescaped `$` while using `\`.

Without escaping, the shell will perform word splitting based on values of `IFS` environment variable (space, tab, newline by default), and pathname expansion on the string (if there is any `*`, `?`, `[]` in filename).

In case a variable, you need to double quote the variable expansion:

```
file='foo bar spam.txt'
echo "$file"
```

Simple `$file` will again fall for the word splitting (and pathname expansion).

Comment: I have update the content above. It still fail. Would you like to test this scrpt? thanks

Comment: @utopiceexpress I think it should be something like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/23450155/

Comment: I had tested this, the result is the woof no launch. I remember I had a similar problem before, I will search all my scripts to find it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. This $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS has an suffix "\x0A", so I update script and all goes OK.

```
#!/bin/bash

port=8080
pkill woof
file=`echo -n $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS|sed 's/\x0A//g'`
echo "->$file<-" >> ~/tmp
woof -c 4 -p $port "$file" &
url=`ifconfig|awk '/inet /&&!/127./{print $2}'|sed 's/.*://'`
qrencode -s 5 -o /tmp/url.png "http://$url:$port"
eog /tmp/url.png && pkill woof
```